# Уместить картинки в прямоугольной области

Tags: алгоритм

Имеется *N* картинок и прямоугольная область. Необходимо подобрать размер картинок так, чтобы они заняли максимальную площадь прямоугольника, т.е. полностью вместились в прямоугольник. Картинки должны быть одинакового размера, разница допустима, если только она не бросается в глаза (лишние пару пикселей у некоторых картинок не страшны). Также, картинки должны меняться в размере пропорционально, опять же разница в несколько пикселей не страшна, если она визуально не заметна. Прикрепляю примеры, как должно быть. 
Нужен алгоритм.
[image: Пример 1][image: Пример 2]

**UPD:**
Скрин к ответу Peter Olson.
[image: Скрин ответа 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начнём с самым простым алгоритмом (грубая сила): попробуем уместить картинки в одном столбцом, потом в двух, трёх, и т.д. до N, чтобы найти количество столбцов, соответствующее на максимальную плошадь.

```js
function bestDimensions(N, aspect, width, height) {
  var maxArea = 0;
  var bestWidth, bestHeight;
  for (var cols = 1; cols <= N; cols++) {
    var rows = Math.ceil(N / cols);
    var w = width / cols;
    if ((w / aspect) * rows > height) {
      w = height * aspect / rows;
    }
    var h = w / aspect;
    var area = N * w * h;
    if (area > maxArea) {
      maxArea = area;
      bestWidth = w;
      bestHeight = h;
    }
  }
  return [bestWidth, bestHeight];
}

// Следующий код не алгоритм. Это просто код для демо.
byId("show").onclick = function() {
  var width = +byId("width").value,
    height = +byId("height").value,
    aspect = +byId("aspect").value,
    N = +byId("N").value;
  var dimensions = bestDimensions(N, aspect, width, height);
  var imageWidth = dimensions[0],
    imageHeight = dimensions[1];
  var canvas = byId("canvas");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  var ct = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var x = 0,
    y = 0;
  while (N--) {
    ct.beginPath();
    ct.rect(x, y, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    ct.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    ct.fill();
    ct.lineWidth = 1;
    ct.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ct.stroke();
    if (x + imageWidth > width - imageWidth) {
      x = 0;
      y += imageHeight;
    } else {
      x += imageWidth;
    }
  }
};

function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
N:<input id="N" type="text" value="12"><br>
Cоотношение сторон:<input id="aspect" type="text" value="1"><br>
Высота:<input id="height" type="text" value="500"><br>
Ширина:<input id="width" type="text" value="300"><br>
<button id="show">Показать</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Это конечно не оптимальный алгоритм, хотя довольно простой, и по-моему достаточно быйстрый: код для показа картинок будет намного медленее.

ПРАВКА: Использую `canvas` вместо HTML `div`ов. Теперь не выходит за границу области.

Comment: Пока в алгоритм не вникал, но потестировал на некоторых данных, и завалился на N = 600, w = 500, h = 300;
Скрин прикреплю к вопросу.

Comment: Понял, косячно выводилось из-за стиля, алгоритм не при чем.

Comment: @nuts119 Да, было бы лучше в канвасе, очень маленькие divы не так хорошо работают.

Comment: У вас перепутаны input-поля `Высота: <input id="width"`

Comment: @Peter Olson Ваш верно работает, хотя и не оптимально.

Comment: @Dmi7ry Ой, спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что пришло в голову, помимо перебора

```
function bestDimensions(images, width, height)
{
    var area = Math.sqrt(width * height / images);
    var square_w = Math.ceil(width / area);
    var square_h = Math.ceil(height / area);
    var sw = width / square_w;
    var sh = height / square_h;
    var sz = Math.floor(Math.max(sw, sh));

    var h = Math.floor(width / sz);
    var v = Math.floor(height / sz);

    if (h * v < images)
    {
        sz = Math.floor(Math.min(sw, sh));
        h = Math.floor(width / sz);
        v = Math.floor(height / sz);
    }

    return sz;
}
```

На входе:
`width` - ширина области в пикселях
`height` - высота области в пикселях
`images` - количество изображений

На выходе:
`sz` - размер изображения в пикселях (изображение квадратное);
`h` - максимальное количество изображений по горизонтали;
`v` - максимальное количество изображений по вертикали;

**upd:** изменил код на JavaScript

Comment: Примерно также пытался, но при некотором количестве картинки выходили за границу области.

Comment: @nuts119 Так проверьте. Я смотрел некоторые диапазоны - работает нормально.

Comment: Извините, на Вашем алгоритме пока все работает хорошо. Это тупанул. Сейчас еще посмотрю разные вариации, тогда чуть позже отмечу как верный.

Comment: @nuts119 кажется, я нашел случай, когда некорректно будет работать. Сейчас попробую исправить

Comment: @nuts119 Поправил, добавилась ещё одна проверка. По поводу ответа Peter Olson... Я совсем не специалист в JS, а с HTML/CSS вообще дел почти не имел, но в ответе  перепутаны значения input-полей (**Высота**: <input id="**width**") и, скорее всего, некорректно _отображается_ результат на экране, но при этом, сам алгоритм работает корректно. Думаю так потому, что если туда подставить мой код (исправив input поля width/height), он будет точно так же отображаться (вылезая за пределы чёрного прямоугольника), хотя _не в браузере_ рисует всё правильно.

Comment: @nuts119 не влез комментарий. В общем, если там поставить заполнение width/height как 100%, то по вертикали всё равно будет отступ между строками - из-за этого и вылезает за пределы чёрного прямоугольника.

Comment: Попробуйте у себя посмотреть с такими данными: N = 296, w = 491; h = 708; У меня последние две картинки вылезают за границу.
По поводу ответа Peter Olson: я это тоже заметил и все это потом учел, и опечатку с id в div и вертикальные отступы между строками, в итоге, алгоритм правильно работает.

Comment: @nuts119 `N = 296, w = 491; h = 708; ` с последней правкой работает корректно

Comment: На N = 296, w = 791; h = 508 заваливается

Comment: @nuts119 В коде опечатка была, строка должна быть `var h = Math.floor(width / sz);` при переносе сюда скопировал старый код.

Comment: @nuts119 похоже, две проверки стали лишними после последнего исправления, соответственно, код упростился

Comment: @nuts119 при тщательном тестировании на свежую голову обнаружил, что в некоторых случаях размер подбирается не оптимальный. Прямо сейчас нет времени поискать решение, но как появится, попробую исправить

Comment: Какие случаи можете указать? И что-нибудь придумали новое?

Comment: @nuts119 пока, к сожалению, занят и освобожусь не раньше, чем через неделю. Случаи - width 480, height 190, 24 images - 60 пикселей,  25 images - 47 пикселей, 26 images - 53 пикселя. Размер с 25 изображениями некорректный - должен быть такой же, как и с 26 изображениями.

Answer (score 2):

Улучшил алгоритм, теперь поиск занимает обычно около 5 итераций.

---

Исправил несколько ошибок.

---

Вот ещё один вариант, на WPF.

Переменные: `PicMargin` — маргин вокруг картинки, `PicQuantity` — количество картинок, `PicWidth`/`PicHeight` — высота/ширина нерастянутой картинки, `TargetSpace.ActualWidth`/`TargetSpace.ActualHeight` — размер области, где нужно разметить картинки. Как `alpha` обозначен коэффициент растяжения картинки. Алгоритм находит максимальное возможное значение `alpha`.

```
// подсчёт alpha для данного к-ва строк и столбцов
double CalcAlpha(int m, int n)
{
    // m * (alpha * w + margin) + margin <= clientW <=> 
    //      alpha <= ((clientW - margin)/m - margin)/w
    // n * (alpha * h + margin) + margin <= clientH <=>
    //      alpha <= ((clientH - margin)/n - margin)/h
    var clientW = TargetSpace.ActualWidth - PicMargin;
    var clientH = TargetSpace.ActualHeight - PicMargin;

    return Math.Min(((clientW - PicMargin)/m - PicMargin)/PicWidth,
                    ((clientH - PicMargin)/n - PicMargin)/PicHeight);
}

// оценка нужного количества строк
double EstimateM()
{
    var clientW = TargetSpace.ActualWidth - PicMargin;
    var clientH = TargetSpace.ActualHeight - PicMargin;
    // m * picW : n * picH = clientW : clientH, m : n = (clientW * picH) : (clientH * picW)
    var approxAspectRatio = (double)(clientW * PicHeight) / (clientH * PicWidth);
    // m * n = PicQuantity => m * m = approxAspectRatio * PicQuantity
    return Math.Sqrt(approxAspectRatio * PicQuantity);
}

// подсчёт лучшего alpha
void Update()
{
    int iterations = 0;
    double bestAlpha = double.NegativeInfinity;
    int bestM = 0, bestN = 0;
    var mApprox = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)Math.Round(EstimateM()), 1), PicQuantity);

    // ищем наилучший вариант вверх и вниз от оценочного значения
    // поскольку качество решения зависит от к-ва строк горкой,
    // можно выходить из цикла как только началось ухудшение
    for (int m = mApprox; m <= PicQuantity; m++)
    {
        iterations++;
        // берём необходимое количество столбцов
        int n = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)PicQuantity / m);
        // и вычисляем alpha для этого случая
        var currAlpha = CalcAlpha(m, n);
        if (currAlpha < bestAlpha)
            break;
        // запоминаем текущий лучший результат
        bestAlpha = currAlpha;
        bestM = m;
        bestN = n;
    }
    // то же вниз
    for (int m = mApprox - 1; m >= 1; m--)
    {
        iterations++;
        int n = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)PicQuantity / m);
        var currAlpha = CalcAlpha(m, n);
        if (currAlpha < bestAlpha)
            break;
        bestAlpha = currAlpha;
        bestM = m;
        bestN = n;
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("Iterations: " + iterations);

    TargetSpace.Children.Clear();
    if (bestAlpha > 0)
        PlacePictures(bestM, bestN, bestAlpha);
    else
        TargetSpace.Children.Add(
            new TextBlock() { Text = "Impossible", Foreground = Brushes.Red });
}

// вывод
void PlacePictures(int m, int n, double alpha)
{
    double xstep = PicMargin + PicWidth * alpha,
           ystep = PicMargin + PicHeight * alpha;
    // центрируем по горизонтали
    double x0 = PicMargin + (TargetSpace.ActualWidth - PicMargin - m * xstep) / 2,
           y0 = PicMargin;
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            PlacePictureAt(x0 + i * xstep, y0 + j * ystep, alpha);
    // отдельно центрируем последнюю строку
    var remainingPictures = PicQuantity - (n - 1) * m;
    x0 = PicMargin + (TargetSpace.ActualWidth - PicMargin - remainingPictures * xstep) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < remainingPictures; i++)
        PlacePictureAt(x0 + i * xstep, y0 + (n - 1) * ystep, alpha);
}
```

Полный код:

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace PicturePlacement
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TargetSpace.SizeChanged += (o, args) => Update();
            Update();
        }

        double CalcAlpha(int m, int n)
        {
            // m * (alpha * w + margin) + margin <= clientW  <=>  alpha <= ((clientW - margin)/m - margin)/w
            // n * (alpha * h + margin) + margin <= clientH  <=>  alpha <= ((clientH - margin)/n - margin)/h
            var clientW = TargetSpace.ActualWidth - PicMargin;
            var clientH = TargetSpace.ActualHeight - PicMargin;

            return Math.Min(((clientW - PicMargin)/m - PicMargin)/PicWidth,
                            ((clientH - PicMargin)/n - PicMargin)/PicHeight);
        }

        double EstimateM()
        {
            var clientW = TargetSpace.ActualWidth - PicMargin;
            var clientH = TargetSpace.ActualHeight - PicMargin;
            // m * picW : n * picH = clientW : clientH, m : n = (clientW * picH) : (clientH * picW)
            var approxAspectRatio = (double)(clientW * PicHeight) / (clientH * PicWidth);
            // m * n = PicQuantity => m * m = approxAspectRatio * PicQuantity
            return Math.Sqrt(approxAspectRatio * PicQuantity);
        }

        void Update()
        {
            int iterations = 0;
            double bestAlpha = double.NegativeInfinity;
            int bestM = 0, bestN = 0;
            var mApprox = Math.Min(Math.Max((int)Math.Round(EstimateM()), 1), PicQuantity);
            for (int m = mApprox; m <= PicQuantity; m++)
            {
                iterations++;
                int n = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)PicQuantity / m);
                var currAlpha = CalcAlpha(m, n);
                if (currAlpha < bestAlpha)
                    break;
                bestAlpha = currAlpha;
                bestM = m;
                bestN = n;
            }
            for (int m = mApprox - 1; m >= 1; m--)
            {
                iterations++;
                int n = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)PicQuantity / m);
                var currAlpha = CalcAlpha(m, n);
                if (currAlpha < bestAlpha)
                    break;
                bestAlpha = currAlpha;
                bestM = m;
                bestN = n;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Iterations: " + iterations);

            TargetSpace.Children.Clear();
            if (bestAlpha > 0)
                PlacePictures(bestM, bestN, bestAlpha);
            else
                TargetSpace.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Impossible", Foreground = Brushes.Red });
        }

        void PlacePictures(int m, int n, double alpha)
        {
            double xstep = PicMargin + PicWidth * alpha, ystep = PicMargin + PicHeight * alpha;
            double x0 = PicMargin + (TargetSpace.ActualWidth - PicMargin - m * xstep) / 2, y0 = PicMargin;
            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
                for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
                    PlacePictureAt(x0 + i * xstep, y0 + j * ystep, alpha);
            var remainingPictures = PicQuantity - (n - 1) * m;
            x0 = PicMargin + (TargetSpace.ActualWidth - PicMargin - remainingPictures * xstep) / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < remainingPictures; i++)
                PlacePictureAt(x0 + i * xstep, y0 + (n - 1) * ystep, alpha);
        }

        void PlacePictureAt(double x, double y, double alpha)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle() { Height = PicHeight * alpha, Width = PicWidth * alpha, Fill = Brushes.Green };
            Canvas.SetLeft(r, x);
            Canvas.SetTop(r, y);
            TargetSpace.Children.Add(r);
        }

        #region propdp int PicHeight
        public int PicHeight
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(PicHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PicHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PicHeightProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("PicHeight", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(1, (o, args) => ((MainWindow)o).Update()));
        #endregion

        #region propdp int PicWidth
        public int PicWidth
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(PicWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PicWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PicWidthProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("PicWidth", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(1, (o, args) => ((MainWindow)o).Update()));
        #endregion

        #region propdp int PicQuantity
        public int PicQuantity
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(PicQuantityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PicQuantityProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PicQuantityProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("PicQuantity", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(1, (o, args) => ((MainWindow)o).Update()));
        #endregion

        #region propdp int PicMargin
        public int PicMargin
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(PicMarginProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PicMarginProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PicMarginProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("PicMargin", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(10, (o, args) => ((MainWindow)o).Update()));
        #endregion
    }
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="PicturePlacement.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Rectangle packing" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=ClientWidthBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Client W:</Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="ClientWidthBox" Text="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=TargetSpace, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="40" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <Grid Width="10"/>
            <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=ClientHeightBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Client H:</Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="ClientHeightBox" Text="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TargetSpace, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="40" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <Grid Width="10"/>
            <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=WidthBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Width:</Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="WidthBox" Text="{Binding PicWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <Grid Width="10"/>
            <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=HeightBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Height:</Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="HeightBox" Text="{Binding PicHeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <Grid Width="10"/>
            <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=QuantityBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Quantity:</Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="QuantityBox" Text="{Binding PicQuantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="40"/>
            <Grid Width="10"/>
            <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=MarginBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Margin:</Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="MarginBox" Text="{Binding PicMargin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="40"/>
        </WrapPanel>
        <Canvas x:Name="TargetSpace" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```